# Location of olecranon

Tags: pain, bones, joints, elbow

I've read that your olecranon is the tip of your elbow.

But what about the point that I've marked with the green `X` on the below image?

If you were getting pain there, would it still be classed as olecranon pain? As to me it feels like my elbow, but it isn't quite the very tip of it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the X in the image is just below the olecranon. Pain in X could arise from the olecranon bursa or muscle tendons, for example, and you could still call it "olecranon pain" - this is not a name of a specific condition; it just tells a symptom location.

The olecranon is not just a small spot where the black line in the image ends but the entire bony bump from the top of the bone down to X.

Comment: Thanks, I read that tight triceps can result in olecranon pain, which I have a feeling might be causing it in my case

Comment: The triceps muscle tendon is attached to the upper part of the olecranon ( [link](http://howtorelief.com/triceps-brachii-origin-insertion-nerve-supply-action/) ) and tight triceps may cause olecranon pain, but I think this pain would be higher from where the X is. There are tendons of some forearm muscles that are attached lower (closer to X). T